# for some or for all

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations, quantifiers

The following text is from Velleman's `How to Prove` book from the reflexive closure section:

> According to the definition we gave in the last section, the relation $L =
> \{(x, y) \in R × R \mid x ≤ y\}$ is a total order on $R$, but the relation $M = \{(x, y) ∈
> R × R | x < y\}$ is not because it is not reflexive. Of course, these relations are
>   closely related. It’s clear that $M \subseteq L$, and the only ordered pairs in $L$ that are
>   not in M are pairs of the form (x, x), for some x ∈ R.

My doubt is with respect to the last sentence. Isn't the only ordered pairs in $L$ which are not in M is $\forall x \in R((x,x) \in L)$. Then why is it said for some $x \in R$ rather than forall $x \in R$ ?

Comment: You are correct in saying that it concerns all $x\in R$. But also you have nothing to worry about. "for some" is used her in the context of "are of the form (x,x)...".

Comment: @drhab Thanks for confirming it. I thought I was misunderstanding something about quantifiers. Can you post this as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow its both: The ordered pairs in $L\setminus M$ are **all** pairs for which there **exists** an $x$ such that the pair is $(x,x)$. The "all" is dropped in the original formulation from "(all) pairs of the form" and the "exists" is contained in "for some $x$".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that it concerns *all* $x\in R$. The author is using "for some" in the context of "are of the form $(x,x)$...".